# Optimize cost BigQuery queries

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have a BigQuery table, called 'table1'. This table has 1Tb of data in it. It has this schema:

```
col1, col2, col3, timestamp
```

I would like for each timestamp YYYYMMDD found in 'table1' to make a table called 'table_YYYYMMDD' containing the data from 'table1' with the YYYYMMDD timestamp.

My idea is to make this query (here for the timestamp 20200421 for example):

```
select col1, col2, col3, timestamp from table1 where string(timestamp) like '*2020-04-21*'
```

and to run it this way:

```
bq query --destination_table table_20200421 --use_legacy_sql=false --append --allow_large_results select col1, col2, col3, timestamp from table1 where string(timestamp) like '*2020-04-21*'
```

and to just run this for every date I want.
The problem is, each time this request runs, it analyses 1Tb of data, which comes out expensive if you do it for like 200 dates.
Is there a more cost effective way to achieve the same result with BigQuery? 
May be extracting the table to Storage as JSON data and analyzing it another way ( spark ? )

Thank you for you help

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `LIKE`, as it has to read the whole thing to know if it exists within the value and can't really skip records.

Try using `WHERE TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(timestamp, DAY) = TIMESTAMP('2020-04-21')`

Now, the most elegant (and in my opinion correct) solution would actually be to partition the table. This can be done fairly easily by copying over the table to a version that you configured as partitioned by the `timestamp` field. I can add details about this if you don't have any particular constrains about partitioning.

Comment: Actually my table is partitioned ( I didnt notice as I didn't make it) and with your version of the request, it only analyses 4Go out of 1Tb, it's great thanks a lot ! However I don't understand why my where clause makes it analyses the whole data when yours only needs to read 4Gb ? Doesn't it have to read the exact same data (the timestamp field) in both requests to figure out if it matches the condition or not ?

Comment: BigQuery performs full scan in your table (or your partition). If you want to reduce this, you can clusterize your table. A cluster is like a compound index. You can have up to 3 field (f1,f2,f3) and you can only filter with clustering on f2 only if f1 is also filtered, else the clustering feature isn't used

Comment: The way it "reads" is very different in both cases. I am paraphrasing here. If the table is partitioned by date, each "segment" of the table will be associated to a date, then doing date-to-date comparisons is very straightforward. On the other hand, if you run something like `STRING(field) LIKE "%02%", it will have not only to convert all the individual values of your field to string, but also compare with every substring if there is a 02. The "index" for dates created in the example 1 is no longer useful to filter data early, as it still needs to operate all individual values